# Números em formatação de cpf (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

Eu recebo números de um cpf vindo da API, aí ela vai pra uma table que eu fiz, só que os números nao estão em formato de cpf xxx.xxx.xxx-xx e eu gostaria que ficasse, mas nao sei como. É só clicar em logar e já vai pro site onde tem a tabela, aí la a API vai colocar os dados que tem nela do usuário, e nela vem junto o cpf, mas sem formato correto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o Plugin Jquery Mask

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
});
```

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="cpf" id="cpf" maxlength="14">
```